# Why I got error when try to load gltTF using Autodesk Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, gltf

I tried to load the model locally, but came across this problem. I'm using react here.

```
viewer.start();
viewer.setTheme("light-theme");
viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.glTF").then(() => {
  viewer.loadModel("./2floor.gltf");
});
```

});

This is the error I got :
[gltf forge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyEBM.png)

And can I load 2 model in one viewer ?

1. Load from model derivative
2. Load glTF locally

Answer (score 0):

Here's all the code that's needed for the client side:

```
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer({ accessToken: '' }, async function () { const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(document.getElementById('preview'));
    viewer.start();
    viewer.setTheme('light-theme');
    await viewer.loadExtension('Autodesk.glTF');
    //viewer.loadModel('models/rac_basic_sample_project/gltf/model.gltf');
    viewer.loadModel('models/Sponza/glTF/Sponza.gltf');
});
```

Please follow https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/gltf-20-support-forge-viewer for the solution.